# when plotting several data file, last files are abandon from plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My code in gnuplot (**.p file) is:

```
 plot '3exp0346.dat' u 1:2 w lp lt 7 lc rgb 'black' lw 2 title 'Present study' ,\
  '3exp0346.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 4 lc rgb 'blue' title 'Exp in [3]' ,\
  '3num0346.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc rgb 'blue' title 'Num in [3]' ,\
  '2num0346.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 lc rgb 'red' title 'Num in [2]' ,\
  '3exp02306.dat' u 1:2 w lp lt 7 lc rgb 'black' lw 2 ,\
  '3exp02306.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 4 lc rgb 'blue' ,\
  '3num02306.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc rgb 'blue' ,\
  '2num02306.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 lc rgb 'red' ,\
  '3exp0173.dat' u 1:2 w lp lt 7 lc rgb 'black' lw 2 ,\
  '3exp0173.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 4 lc rgb 'blue' 2 ,\
  '3num0173.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc rgb 'blue' ,\
  '2num0173.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 lc rgb 'red' ,\
  '3exp00865.dat' u 1:2 w lp lt 7 lc rgb 'black' lw 2 ,\
  '3exp00865.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 4 lc rgb 'blue' ,\
  '3num00865.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc rgb 'blue' ,\
  '2num00865.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 lc rgb 'red'
```

Loading this code on gnuplot console following error appears

```
"meltcomp.p", line 28: ';' expected
```

then, Closing the console, graph will plot like this:

[image]

But last 4 data files are not present.

What would be problem in this case?

Comment: Which line is 28? Are you sure you have nothing after the \\ (backslash) char ?

Comment: problem has founded. Thanks.

Comment: ok, so which one was it? If you want to share a solution that might be helpful for someone else, answer yourself. In case it was only a typo, consider removing the question, otherwise it might get flagged as invalid (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: As @bibi said, SO allows and even welcomes you answering your own question - there is even a badge for it.  If you have solved this, please write up an answer and accept it.  That way it will help anybody else who encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

problem was 11 line. I am not allowed to leave comment.

```
 '3exp0173.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 4 lc rgb 'blue' 2 ,\
```

in which 2 after color command makes problem. 2 shouldn't be there.